# How to get the compressed data size from a TIdTCPServer?

Tags: indy10, delphi-10-seattle

I'm developing a TCP Client-Server application.

I'm trying to get the compressed size of the packets I send to the client so I can compare that size with the uncompressed data size and get statistics about the compression ratio obtained.

On the Client side. I can get that information comparing the size of the sent/received data with the size I get from the OnSend/OnReceive events of `TIdCompressionIntercept`. Just getting the length of the `ABuffer` parameter of those event handlers.

But, on the Server side, the TIdServerCompressionIntercept does't have those events to hook.

So the question. How can I get the compressed size of the packets sent/received by the server, so I can compare those sizes with the raw data size of those packets?

Thanks.

Client side code sample:

---

```
var
    FRawSentSize            ,
    FComrpessedSentSize     ,
    FRawReceivedSize        ,
    FCompressedReceivedSize : UInt64;

function TFrom1.SendAndReceive( const ToSend: String ): String;
begin
    TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn( ToSend );
    Inc( FRawSentSize, Length( ToSend ) );
    Result := TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn;
    Inc( FRawReceivedSize, Length( Result ) );
end;

function TForm1.CompressorSend( ASender: TIdConnectionIntercept; var ABuffer: TIdBytes );
begin
    Inc( FComrpessedSentSize, Length( ABuffer ) );
end;

function TForm1.CompressorReceive( ASender: TIdConnectionIntercept; var ABuffer: TIdBytes );
begin
    Inc( FCompressedReceivedSize, Length( ABuffer ) );
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TIdServerCompressionIntercept` is not the intercept that does the actual work,  so that is why it has no events.

When a new client connects to the server, `TIdServerCompressionIntercept` will create a `TIdCompressionIntercept` object that gets assigned to the `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Intercept` property.  That object does the actual work, just like in the client-side code.  Your server's `OnConnect` or `OnExecute` event handler can programmably assign handlers to that object's events as needed.

Comment: Now that's a solution! Thanks a lot Gambit!